# Error when starting spring-boot app. How to find out which dependency is causing AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I'm having an error as the below when I'm starting my program.

```
AbstractMethodError org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.supportsSourceType
```

This is after I have added the below to my pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <includeSystemScope>false</includeSystemScope>
    <layout>ZIP</layout>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The reason which I added this is for the purpose to externalize some of the libraries to directly reference to it from runtime classpath:

```
nohup java -cp MyProject.jar -Dloader.path=/path/lib/ org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher &
```

Full pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>parent proj</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>R2-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <axis2.version>1.7.9</axis2.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>project</groupId>
            <artifactId>project</artifactId>
            <version>R2-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Developers Tools-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Camel Spring Test-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Clean Up directory-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Workflow Jars -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-jaxws</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>1.7.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.21</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.21</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>MyProject</finalName>
        <plugins>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includeSystemScope>false</includeSystemScope>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Parent Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>parent proj</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>R2-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>project1</module>
    <module>project2</module>
    <module>project3</module>
</modules>

<name>proj</name>
<description>proj</description>

<properties>
    <revision>R2-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    <springboot.version>2.1.8.RELEASE</springboot.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <camel.version>3.0.0-RC1</camel.version>
    <!-- <camel.version>2.20.1</camel.version> -->
    <log4j.version>1.7.26</log4j.version>
    <jackson.version>2.8.10</jackson.version>
    <saxon.version>9.8.0-8</saxon.version>
    <axis2.version>1.7.9</axis2.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-activemq</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.60</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-remote</artifactId>
        <version>9.1.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
        <version>Brussels-SR4</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

[Screenshot of my error on runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eImWN.png)

Please help! Thanks

**Spring boot version 2.1.8.RELEASE for all**

[Camel Spring Boot Context 5.1.9 RELEASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33jOu.png)

I have found out ConfigurableApplicationContext is referencing spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE

Comment: The stack trace shows the classes that are incompatible. Once you know the classes, it should be a simple matter of figuring out which JAR file they are from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you don't have spring boot dependencies in your project(i believe you have it in MyPrject.jar) So try to declare in your `pom.xml` file  `spring-boot dependencies` with scope `provided`. It might help.

Here you can find documentation of maven dependency scopes:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Thanks, but I see my ConfigurableApplicationContext is referencing to org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile while all my Spring version are 2.1.8.RELEASE. Does it affects?

Comment: 2.1.8.RELEASE - spring boot version. And under it Spring 5 +. Let's say spring boot is framework for frameworks spring 5 and other. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.18.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html

Answer (score 0):

seems it's related to your config file

use -X flag with your maven command to see the full stack trace

`mvn -X spring-boot:run`